# Benefits of usemin?

Tags: javascript, build, gruntjs, build-process, grunt-usemin

I've recently accepted a new project that's using usemin/uglify (with Grunt) for script concatenation/minification, but I can't seem to find what the benefit of usemin is. Is it just that it uses an html template as it's configuration? It seems like it would be a better solution just to do it through uglify. What are the benefits of using usemin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**What does usemin do?**

`usemin` will take a set of *either* CSS or JS and do the following:

1. concatenate the files found within usmin blocks in your HTML
2. uglify or cssmin the concatenated files
3. revision the output file using a hash based on file contents
4. replace the block of css/scripts with a single reference to the usemin output file

**What benefit is offered by this?**

First, concatenation is done in the order the files are listed in your usemin blocks.  Thus, if you have one JS module/script that is dependent upon another being loaded first, you can easily see the order in the HTML and make edits.

Of course, concatenating a directory full of scripts can be done without usemin, but you'll wind up handling this in your gruntfile.  Which one is better -- in the HTML or in the gruntfile?  That's your call, based upon the kind of work you're doing.

Second, the HTML being updated with the revision hash is nice.  If the files in the block were updated between pushes, it cache-busts for you as the hash changes.

**Common issues** that I've run into...and other people have also encountered:

- If you have a *huge* list of scripts, it can be a pain to tweak the HTML every time the scripts change.  I've run into this when working with a SPA framework AND once with a crazy elaborate set of CSS files that were generated from LESS.  You could say the root cause in both cases was a different tool/tech...but usemin didn't make either situation easier.
- The usemin block directory syntax is clunky.  There are directories named in the gruntfile and also in the HTML.  You have to play with it a little for it to make sense.
- Usemin is overkill if you have a very small number of files...like one or two.

**Bottom line** is that as with all tools, there's some sweet spot where usemin will make things easier...or harder.  If you have a handful of files that you want concatenated and minified, usemin can make this easy to manage.  If you have hundreds of files?  You probably don't want usemin.